# What is the geometric term for a higher-dimensional "X"?

Tags: geometry

I am thinking of a family of objects, and would like to put a name to it. In two dimensions drawn on a plane it would appear to be the "X" shape with four terminating vertices connected by 'arms' and one central point. In three dimensions it would still like an "X" shape from certain 2d projections, but rotating around it would appear to have eight vertices at the ends of the 'arms' and one central point.

In the $n$-dimensional case the shape will always have a central point with $2^{n}$ extruded 'arms' going out from it. Each arm has equal length.

What is the more formal term for this object?

Comment: In $n$ dimensions, you can have at most $n$ pairwise-orthogonal directions (exemplified by the coordinate axes), hence there are at most $2n$ (not $2^n$, unless $n=2$) terminating vertices at the ends of orthogonal arms. ... On the other hand, an $n$-dimensional cube has $2^n$ vertices, joined in pairs by diagonals that all pass through the center; however, those diagonals are not orthogonal.

Comment: @Blue You're absolutely right. The orthogonality part of my question is incorrect, and I will remove it. Effectively we are talking about those arms reaching out to the points of a hypercube.

Comment: So I'd just call it the set of body diagonals of the hypercube.